# transfer list items into mySql database via for loop

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python list that is simply 1,2,3,4.... except in this format '0001', '0002', '0003, .... as strings. I want to send 1 million of these to the database but I can't even send 1000 without issues with time. My code looks like this...

```
with db_connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = "INSERT INTO uniqueIdentifiers(uniqueID) VALUES (%s)" 
    for i in range(len(valueStrings)):
        tuple_2 = (valueStrings[i]) 
        cursor.execute(query, tuple_2)
```

This works but it has a rate of about 100 values per 5 seconds which is waaaay too slow for what I need. Is there a more optimal way of achieving this?

Comment: You need a comma to make it a tuple: `(valueStrings[i],)`

Comment: BTW, any time you have a loop over `range(len(somelist))` and then use `somelist[i]` in the loop, should be using `for item in somelist:`

Comment: I am not really sure how this relates to the question of optimization. Can you describe in more detail?

Comment: I think you misunderstand. My code works fine. It is just super slow. Your suggestion will only speed it up a very insignificant amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `executemany()` to insert all of them in a single call.

```
with db_connection.cursor() as cursor:
    query = "INSERT INTO uniqueIdentifiers(uniqueID) VALUES (%s)" 
    params = [(s,) for s in valueStrings] # convert to list of tuples
    cursor.executemany(query, params)
```